# How do I load resource using Class Loader as File?

Tags: java, file, io, classloader, file-handling

I want to open files using the class loader. However I always get a FileNotFoundException. How do I create a new File using the URL? I don't want to open it as a stream just as a file.

```
URL url = VersionUpdater.class.getResource("xslt/screen/foo");
File f = ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a `file://...` URL to `java.io.File`, you'll have to combine both `url.getPath()` and `url.toURI()` for a safe solution:

```
File f;
try {
    f = new File(url.toURI());
} catch(URISyntaxException e) {
    f = new File(url.getPath());
}
```

Full explanations in this [blog post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/04/25/how-convert-javaneturl-javaiofile).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just thinking: What if foo is in a jar? Then you couldn't construct a File.

It should be possible to make it work, if foo is really in a (local) classpath directory - but you know, it will fail, if someone packages it up in a jar, or loads it via the network...